# word press admin not working

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have implemented all the solution to solve the problem occurring in admin end WordPress related to allocated memory

**what I have done**:--

1. Try adding this line to your wp-config.php file: 
   define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');
2. If you have access to your PHP.ini file, change the line in PHP.ini 
   If your line shows 32M try 128M:

   memory_limit = 128M;
3. The maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
   If you don't have access to PHP.ini try adding this to a .htaccess file:

php_value memory_limit 128M

I have also talked with hosting and they said it's from files issue

please suggest the way I can solve the problem, only admin end the problem occurring.

Here is the exact error:

**Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /home4/uavsystems/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1889**

Thanks

Comment: the error indicates that 268MB already are allowed  To me it looks like you are in an endless loop somewhere...

Comment: hello @jeff please check the information of the php https://www.uavsystemsinternational.com/phpinfo.php

Comment: it says `memory_limit 256M`

Comment: so what i need to to i have tried add memory, remove etc but its still not work i have checked all the tricks

Comment: if you check front end the same error coming one of the sections : https://prnt.sc/kelv1m

Comment: as I said already: I think you have a infinite loop somewhere that fills up memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a plugin that uses wp-db.php and causes the `out of memory` issue. You can try to rename the plugin's folders from ftp as follow:  'plugins_name' to become '_plugins_name'. This way you will keep the plugins on your server but they won't be recognized as activated. So do this for all plugins and try again to access wp-admin. Then on success activate the plugins one by one to see which one is causing the memory issue.

But before this try to increase the memory to `512M`. And create a php file (info.php) in your wordpress root directory with only one line:
`<?php php_info(); ?>` and then go to the url http://you-site.com/info.php. Check there if the memory limit that you have set has been applied. And don't forget to delete the file when you got the information you need.

Comment: I have renamed plugins but its then its say nothing totaly stop with 500 error

Comment: Hm, that mean that your theme is dependent on some of the plugins that you have disabled. Try the same with the themes folders and leave only the default one - Twenty Seventeen (if you don't have it - just download it from wordpress.org).

Comment: sorry website is live and i cannot do this , i have renamed last time and there was not any problem

Comment: It is always good to have a staging/development environment for such a cases, where you can also run updates of plugins and themes before running them on live. But still it is good that you managed to recover. It might be that refreshing the activated plugins did cleared some old process in on your server that was connected with the issue.

Comment: if you check front end the same error coming one of the sections : https://prnt.sc/kelv1m

Comment: did you tried to increase the memory limit to 512M and also check if phpinfo() has this updated info.

Comment: And if you have access to cPanel go to the server process option (not sure how it was called) and kill all process. There might be something that is overusing your memory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177413/discussion-between-r-k-bhardwaj-and-ale).

Comment: Thanks for your help it was problem with an stupid plugin